# What does it mean to have square brackets around a genus name?

Tags: taxonomy, classification

For example [Eubacterium] rectale

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The NCBI Taxonomy staff places square brackets around the genus for some species (examples: [Bacillus] aminovorans, [Candida] auris) to indicate that they are misclassified*, meaning placed incorrectly in a higher taxonomic rank.

References:

https://support.nlm.nih.gov/knowledgebase/article/KA-03379/en-us